# Install page for deploying war file in tomcat

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, deployment, war

I am trying to create an installer for my war file. To explain further, I have a GWT project that I made into a war file for deployment in tomcat but I want the program to go to an install page when it is accessed for the first time (just like with Drupal and OpenMRS). And in this install page, I would be able to indicate the database name, the database user and password and the admin details that I would be using for my war file. Also, all my database tables will be loaded once I submit this install page. Can anyone give me tips on how to do this? Thanks

Comment: I would not suggest that at all. Rather write a script to do this.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - Its a server thing, I am not exactly a Tomcat expert,but here goes. When the server loads, read the db config file, it it doesnt exist, catch the exception and redirect the user to the install page (pre created of course, depending on your front end), get the data, create the config file and save. Next time, the config file will be there, and the user wont see the install page.

(My only concern would be some Tomcat constraints that may act up in trying this solution)

You should mark this as a server question to gain attention of tomcat specialists. Also, ask here - https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, creating this install page is a requirement of my client. Is there really no way to do this? :(

Comment: What you are looking for is simple automation. I havent used  Drupal and OpenMRS. So i am sorry but it really isnt clear to me what your requirement is - is it a windows type setup.exe which does all the things? Or is it one time configuration the first time your app is accessed? Is it going to be hosted on your hardware? or each client will have his own server? Is it a one time thing? Is the server windows based, linux based?

Comment: Uhm, this is a one time setup on the first time you access the app. Also, this can be hosted on your local tomcat. So whenever someone deploys my war file and they access it for the first time, the install page will show up and ask for the db details, etc. Sorry if I'm unclear.